Avalonia/ReactiveUI command doesn't execute. Did I miss something?
this is my code:
 public Foo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            ViewModel ??= Locator.Current.GetService<FooViewModel>();

            this.BindInteraction(ViewModel, vm => vm.SetClipboardTextInteration, SetClipboardSelectedTextInteraction)
                .DisposeWith(d);

            //подписка на нажатие + ctrl+c
            var pointerPressedObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<PointerPressedEventArgs>, PointerPressedEventArgs>(
                h => this.PointerPressed += h,
                h => this.PointerPressed -= h)
            .Subscribe(h =>
            {
                if (h.Sender != this && h.Sender is Foo)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("a");
                    this._isSelected = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("a");
                    this._isSelected = true;
                }
            })
            .DisposeWith(d);
            var keyCtrlCPressObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<KeyEventArgs>, KeyEventArgs>(
            h => this.KeyDown += h,
            h => this.KeyDown -= h)
            .Subscribe(h =>
            {
                if(h.EventArgs.Key == Key.C && h.EventArgs.KeyModifiers == KeyModifiers.Control && this._isSelected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("test");
                }
            })
            .DisposeWith(d);

        });
    }

my Foo is ReactiveUserControl. It is a button which darkens when it is selected. I need to use its selection - when it is darkened and when i hit Ctrl+C it gets copied. The problem is that my debugger(Console.WriteLine blocks) doesn't do anything. It doesn't stop on these blocks so they got stepped over. Why?
I think I need to bind them someway but I don't know how

Debug.WriteLine ?

@Sinatr I use Console just for debugger to stop there

You are supposed to set breakpoint on if. Also check that actual subscribing occurs. I haven't used WhenActivated, but I guess you may miss a bit to set it up, so it may not run at all. Set breakpoint on ViewModel ?? =  line, does it gets hit?
